# Is there a nicer way to update a single nested properties inside JS using Spread?

Tags: javascript, setstate, ecmascript-2016, spread

I'm trying to update a single value in a heavily nested configuration object for charting library using `setState()`

Is there a nicer way to use the `spread` to update a single value?

I'm having to do a lot of the following:

```
const newValue = 'somevalue'

setState({
 ...config,
 chart: {
  ...config.chart,
  toolbar: {
   ...config.chart.toolbar,
   tools: {
    ...config.chart.toolbar.tools,
    valueIWantToUpdate: newValue
   }
  }
 }
})
```

Basically I want to avoid doing a lot of `...config.property.property.property`, not sure if this is possible?

Happy to take other suggestions or better ways to do it rather than using the `spread` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with spread operator that is the only way to set property which is deep level down in the object which you want to update. But You can use library like Lodash which has method like merge which can help you merge two object independently of the level of imbrication..

```js
let config = {
  name: "John",
  age: 3,
  gender: "male",
  chart: {},
  toolbar: {
    name: "toolbar-1",
    tools: {
      value: 1
    }
  }
}

const change = {
  chart: {
    name: "John Doe",
    s: 'test'
  },
  toolbar: {
    tools: {
      toolset: "toolset"
    }
  }
}

let result = _.merge(config, change);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but I don't think this method triggers the `re-render` when you put it in `setConfig(result)`.  eg `setConfig(result)`. Unfortunately, I can't share the codebase as it's private and other implications.

Comment: I think the problem isn't related to the way you update the the variable, whenever you call the function which update the State, react trigger de rerender automatically

Answer (score -1):

```
  setState((prevState) => {
    const updatedState = {...prevState};
    updatedState.config.chart.toolbar.tools.valueIWantToUpdate = newValue;
    return updatedState;
  });
```

Comment: I'm using `hooks` version `const [config, setConfig]` but thank anyways, this method didn't trigger the `re-render` of the component. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.